# HighChart and HighStock showing x-axis and y-axis length differently for same chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using same chart in 2 different places and the data is being loaded dynamically.
In one of the place i am using HighChart and for other i use HighStock to get the Navigator,Scrollbar facility.

What i'm trying to achieve is i am loading data asynchronously and the chart shows loading text/a loader until it gets data from the server.This works perfectly fine for HighChart. But when it comes to HighStock things are not working. It shows data differently than what i am expecting it to be.

Let me explain, The chart is initialized first and when it fetches data from server i tried to log the value of xAxis here, it shows 1 for HighChart which is correct but for HighStock the statement show 2 xAxis.

//HighChart

```
var MyChart = {
    initHighcharts: function() {
        this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
             // Chart related configuration
            },
            series: []
        });
        this.chart.showLoading();
    },        

    updateChart: function(data) {

        console.log('x axis', this.chart.xAxis);// Here i get 1 xAxis

        // Load data here

        this.chart.redraw();
        this.chart.hideLoading();
    },
};

MyChart.initHighcharts();
setTimeout(function() {
    var data = someData;      
    MyChart.updateChart(data);
}, 2000);
```

I don't understand what goes wrong here when i change the HighChart to HighStock.The only piece of information i changed here is
`this.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({`

```
 //HighStock chart

    var MyChart = {
        initHighcharts: function() {
            this.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                 // Chart related configuration
                },
                series: []
            });
            this.chart.showLoading();
        },        

        updateChart: function(data) {

            console.log('x axis', this.chart.xAxis);// Here i get 2 xAxis

            // Load data here

            this.chart.redraw();
            this.chart.hideLoading();
        },
    };

    MyChart.initHighcharts();
    setTimeout(function() {
        var data = someData;      
        MyChart.updateChart(data);
    }, 2000)
```

Here are the two fiddle that show the error i am facing,

1. [HighChart Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarojsasmal/t73pm7zj/1/)
2. [HighStock Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarojsasmal/pn5trcoo/3/)

I have logged the length of xAxis, Please open console window to see the xAxis value. Am i doing something wrong here?

Any help is much appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't the second xAxis be the navigator xAxis?

Comment: I don't know. I mean i am still a newbie in HighChart.

Comment: It is the navigator xAxis. Is this an issue? It appears to be working OK to me (although you should use `type: 'datetime'` for the stock chart's xAxis as that is what is intended for these kinds of charts.

Comment: Yeah i have used datetime in my actual chart, But when i insert data the data are inserted in correctly.  Let me explain i have 3 Y-Axes like which i am adding dynamically. It's a two pane highstock chart just like http://jsfiddle.net/marcelojuventino/tc1a78ma/1/.

Comment: The data insert is not inserted into correct axis i don't know why?

Comment: Are you telling each series which yAxis they belong to? Would help to see a jsFiddle of your actual problem.

Comment: Sure, i will in a minute.